# what is icl-twobase1 service

Tags: rhel, services, amazon-ec2

On one of my EC2 instance (RHEL) on AWS, there is a service called icl-twobase1 running on port 25000. Does anyone know what that service is?

Comment: are you sure that's actually the service name, and not just the default protocol name for port 25000? Because "icl-twobase" is what is registered in /etc/services for that port. it's unlikely it's the name of a program. How did you figure this out?

Comment: When I tried to host my own service on port 25000, it got rejected so that tells me there is something running on that port.

Comment: yes, but what is running on that port isn't "icl-twobase1". The *name of the port* (specifically: the registered name of the default protocol using that port) is `icl-twobase1`. What *program* is listening on that port?

Comment: how do I find out what program is running on port 25000?

Comment: for example by running `ss -ltpn` as root and looking in the "Process" column.

Comment: ok. did that. nothing is running on port 25000. then why my service is not able to occupy port 25000. it works on port 25010.

Comment: are you using UDP or TCP?

Comment: figured it out. You are right. I did not specify the port properly. It is working now. Thank you for guiding me thru the process. much appreciated.

Comment: Please write up what exactly you did as an answer and answer your own question!

Comment: I would like you to paste your first comment as an answer so I can accept it and explain what I did in the comment.